# Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack error message

Tags: c#, asp.net

whenever i **Response.Redirect("myexamplepage.aspx");** it either keep looping and then lastly show the page is unable to view or show this above error. However, if i **Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com.sg");** it works.

I tried all the methods i found online such as the following:

1. Response.Redirect(url,false)
2. Redirecting url outside the try-catch

I'd also make sure that my project is running debug mode.

BUT i am still facing this problem. It is like so random because previously i dont have any problems redirecting to my url. Please provide me with solutions thanks.

Comment: I had this error when the "Response.Redirect" command was triggered.
I removed the update panel from the page and resolved

Answer (score 11):

This error occures most of the time when you are trying to redirect to a new page, while the current page is still trying to complete it's proces.

You can find more information about the issue right here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/

So change your code to the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Response.Redirect ("myexamplepage.aspx", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Rob Angelier said, the problem is related to an uncompleted process.
That means, make sure you move the Response.Redirect out of the `using statement`!

This may not be an actual answer to the specific question but I thought it would help others struggling with the same type of problem :)